# Como usar Window.ClientBouds dentro de uma class no XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Estou tendo dificuldades em delimitar o movimento do personagem ao limite da tela.
Na classe `Game1` que é meu main consigo usar `Window.ClientBounds`, mas quando uso esta função dentro da classe `Player1` dá o erro:

> 'The name 'Window' does not exist in the current context'`.

Trecho de código da classe `Player1`:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    position += velocity;

    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
        velocity.Y = -3f;
        if (position.Y + texture.Height > (Game as Game1).Window.ClientBounds.Height)
            velocity.Y += 3f;
    }
    ...
}
```

Quando uso `(Game as Game1)` consigo usar `Window.ClientBounds`, mas ele da um erro que diz:

> 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: E apresentar código? Ou algo que dê para analisar...

Comment: Ajuda ae CesarMiguel!

Comment: Não estou muito dentro dessas classes, mas parece me que o erro `'The name 'Window' does not exist in the current context'` quer dizer que o Window que estás a usar não fazer parte do teu context. Verifica se tens

Answer (score 3):

Faltam informações para uma análise completa da situação, mas pelo que foi possível entender da pergunta, o método `Update` mostrado pertence à classe `Player1`.

Por sua vez, essa classe `Player1` não tem acesso aos membros da classe `Game1`.

Assim, bastaria passar uma instância da classe `Game1` para `Player1`, durante sua criação, para que `Player1` possa acessar tudo relacionado a `Game1`.

Por exemplo:

A classe `Player1` ficaria aproximadamente assim:

```
public class Player1 ... {
    private Game1 myGame;

    //não sei como está o construtor da sua classe Player1, mas agora ele deve possuir
    //um parâmetro a mais: game
    public Player1 (Game1 game) {
        myGame = game;
        ...
    }

    ...

    public void Update(...) {
        ...
        //agora você pode acessar os membros da classe Game1, a partir de Player1
        if (position.Y + texture.Height > myGame.Window.ClientBounds.Height)
        ...
    }
}
```

E na classe `Game1`, onde o `Player1` é instanciado, você deve fazer algo assim:

```
...
Player1 p = new Player1(this);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse Método esta na classe game para usa-lo ou sua classe Terá que herdar a classe game para que você possa fazer uma sobrecarga ou receber Window.ClientBounds como parâmetro em seu método aqui Implementei em uma classe que eu já tinha ela é herdada de minha classe Sprite que Herda A classe game.

```
public class SpriteAnimated : Sprite
{
    Point   FrameSize;
    Point   CurrentFrame;
    Point   SheetSize;
    Vector2 Position;

    int TimeSizeLastFrame = 0;

    private Texture2D SpriteSheet;        

    public SpriteAnimated(Texture2D Textura, Point Size)
    {          
        SpriteSheet = Textura;
        SheetSize = Size;

        int FlameX = Convert.ToInt16(Textura.Width / Size.X);
        int FlameY = Convert.ToInt16(Textura.Height / Size.Y);

        FrameSize.X = FlameX;
        FrameSize.Y = FlameY;

        Position = new Vector2(
                                 (Window.ClientBounds.Width - FrameSize.X) / 2,
                                 (Window.ClientBounds.Height - FrameSize.Y) / 2
                              );

    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, KeyboardState KeyPress, GameWindow Window)
    {
        TimeSizeLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

        if (Position.Y <= Window.ClientBounds.Height)
        { 
            // Aqui Pode Ir seu codigo
        }

        if (KeyPress.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            Position.Y -= 5;
            SpriteSheet = null;
        }
        else if (KeyPress.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            Position.Y += 5;
        }
        else if (KeyPress.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            Position.X -= 5;
        }
        else if (KeyPress.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            Position.X += 5;
        }

        if (TimeSizeLastFrame > 60)
        {
            TimeSizeLastFrame -= 60;
            CurrentFrame.X++;

            if (CurrentFrame.X >= SheetSize.X)
            {
                CurrentFrame.X = 0;
                CurrentFrame.Y++;

                if (CurrentFrame.Y >= SheetSize.Y)
                    CurrentFrame.Y = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw(GameTime gametime, SpriteBatch spriteBacth)
    {           
        spriteBacth.Draw(  SpriteSheet, 
                           Position, 
                           new Rectangle(CurrentFrame.X * FrameSize.X, CurrentFrame.Y * FrameSize.Y, FrameSize.X, FrameSize.Y), 
                           Color.White, 
                           0, 
                           Vector2.Zero, 
                           1, 
                           SpriteEffects.None, 
                           0
                        );
    }
}
```